# commandbutton (active-x) changes pathname of assigned macro

Tags: vba, excel

Not sure if relevant for solution, but just so you see the workflow, file is set up as follows:

- One sheet is called "Template".
- User enters info on another sheet called "Enter Info".
- Click on cmdbutton "open client" and the assigned macro copies the sheet "Template" and renames it using certain data (client name) from the "Enter Info" sheet.

This all works fine.

In the "Template" sheet (which gets copied) I have 2 command buttons and have assigned a macro. The macro is saved "in this worksheet".

Example: "Filename.xls!macro_do_something"

This has worked for 2 years now, but all of a sudden every single button in every single sheet (not just new copies) has been assigned to the macro:
"Filename comp.xls!macro_do_something"

When I click to execute the command I get the message that the file could not be found, which makes sense as it does not exist and never has.

I have never copied the file to a different location, I have never changed the file name. It worked fine and correct for 2 years.

Any ideas how this can happen?? Why would the file name just randomly get changed??

Comment: Have you checked the scope for the assigned macro? Is it set to workbook rather than all open workbooks?

Comment: Hi QHarr. Thanks for your quick answer. Where would this be defined and how does it have an influence if the macro is only used in this file?

Comment: if it is a form control you can right click > assign macro >Macros in. I was just wondering if it is somehow picking up information from elsewhere so limit to ThisWorkbook and see if it makes a difference. I think i have noticed something similar from time to time though it has always been a workbook name i recognise. Otherwise, developer tab > macros > Macros in

Comment: If users have access to the spreadsheet, my guess is one of **them** modified the workbook. (Probably saved it with a different name, then copied sheets into a new workbook to recreate what looks like the original workbook, but forgot to point the macros in the new workbook to refer to the new workbook.)

Comment: Thank you. Only me and one other person using the file (on the same laptop) at different times... I am also using the macro "in this file". Regarding reaching too many sheets, i regularly delete unused sheets (currently about 45 sheets in file). Only special character i found is a dash (example: abc-def). No influence until now, but maybe a recent software  update created a problem with dashes?  I am starting to think maybe there was an error (file crash in the background?) during a backup process??

Answer (score 0):

As you've been cloning sheets for two years, the workbook could have reached some maximum number of sheets. Some magical 32, 64, 512 etc. Perhaps reaching such a limit would produce an unexpected behaviour, like changing the file name in the buttons assignment.

One other thing you could check for is the presence of a special character in the sheet names the workbook assigns after the client names.